# Calculate downtime based on status 'UP' / 'DOWN'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query that will output the average downtime of all of the machines per day, based on the status which is 'UP' OR 'DOWN'

The code of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Machine_Status(
m_ID INT,
mo_time_stamp DATETIME,
mo_status VARCHAR(4), #UP/DOWN
FOREIGN KEY (m_ID) REFERENCES Machine (m_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (m_ID, mo_time_stamp)
);
```

The inserted values are:

```
╔═══════╦═════════════════════╦══════╗
║ 31001 ║ 2020-07-18 06:00:00 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31001 ║ 2020-07-19 04:30:00 ║ DOWN ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31001 ║ 2020-07-19 05:55:30 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31001 ║ 2020-07-20 19:28:10 ║ DOWN ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31001 ║ 2020-07-20 21:04:05 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31002 ║ 2020-07-19 06:00:00 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31002 ║ 2020-07-20 04:30:00 ║ DOWN ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31002 ║ 2020-07-20 05:55:30 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31002 ║ 2020-07-21 19:28:10 ║ DOWN ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31002 ║ 2020-07-21 21:04:05 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31003 ║ 2020-07-23 06:00:00 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31003 ║ 2020-07-24 04:30:00 ║ DOWN ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31003 ║ 2020-07-24 05:55:30 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31003 ║ 2020-07-25 19:28:10 ║ DOWN ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31003 ║ 2020-07-25 21:04:05 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31004 ║ 2020-07-25 06:00:00 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31004 ║ 2020-07-26 04:30:00 ║ DOWN ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31004 ║ 2020-07-26 05:55:30 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31004 ║ 2020-07-27 19:28:10 ║ DOWN ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31004 ║ 2020-07-27 21:04:05 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31005 ║ 2020-07-28 06:00:00 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31005 ║ 2020-07-29 04:30:00 ║ DOWN ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31005 ║ 2020-07-29 05:55:30 ║ UP   ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31005 ║ 2020-07-30 19:28:10 ║ DOWN ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════╣
║ 31005 ║ 2020-07-30 21:04:05 ║ UP   ║
╚═══════╩═════════════════════╩══════╝
```

I am trying to get an output of this sort:

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║ average_downtime_perday ║
╠═════════════════════════╣
║ 03:10:18                ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

*The time I wrote here^ is just for the example*

I would also like to check it between dates and not include dates that were not submitted (to check the downtime of days there were marked as up or down)

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show us the results that you want for this sample data.

Comment: @RonSwanson . . . This is much more complicated than you think because a machine could be up (or down) for multiple days in a row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Do you think I should have 2 time frames?
start time (UP) end time (UP)
start time(DOWN) end time (UP)?

Comment: @RonSwanson . . . That doesn't make a difference, because you still have the issue of spanning days.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions (if you are running MySQL 8.0).

It is not very clear which results you want - as an example, this gives you the total downtime per machine, in seconds:

```
select 
    mo_id,
    sum(timestampdiff(second, mo_time_stamp, lead_ mo_time_stamp)) total_downtime
from (
    select 
        m.*, 
        lead(mo_time_stamp) over(partition by m_id order by mo_time_stamp) lead_ mo_time_stamp
    from Machine_Status m
) m
where mo_status = 'DOWN'
group by mo_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with day boundaries.  The simplest solution is to assume that you have a calendar table -- which can be constructed from a recursive CTE or another method.

Then, you can use `join` to get the dates corresponding to each period for each machine and lots of arithmetic.  So:

```
select c.date,
       sum(case when m.mo_status = 'UP'
                then timestampdiff(second,
                                   greatest(c.date, m.mo_time_stamp),
                                   least(c.date + interval 1 day, m.next_mo_time_stamp)
                                  )
                else 0
           end) as up_time,
       sum(case when m.mo_status = 'DOWN'
                then timestampdiff(second,
                                   greatest(c.date, m.mo_time_stamp),
                                   least(c.date + interval 1 day, m.next_mo_time_stamp)
                                  )
                else 0
           end) as down_time
from (select m.*, lead(mo_time_stamp, 1, curdate()) over (partition by m_id order by mo_time_stamp) as next_mo_time_stamp
      from machine_status m
     )  join
     calendar c
     on c.date >= date(mo_time_stamp) and c.date <= date(next_mo_time_stamp)
where c.date between ? and ?
group by c.date
order by c.date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebbb542385ec2789cd6e5c4ee1adca03) is a db<>fiddle illustrating this logic.

If you want the average downtime over a range of days:

```
select (sum(case when m.mo_status = 'DOWN'
                 then timestampdiff(second,
                                    greatest(c.date, m.mo_time_stamp),
                                    least(c.date + interval 1 day, m.next_mo_time_stamp)
                                   )
                 else 0
             end) /
         (timestampdiff(day, min(c.date), max(c.date)) + 1)
        ) as down_time_seconds_per_day
from (select m.*, lead(mo_time_stamp, 1, curdate()) over (partition by m_id order by mo_time_stamp) as next_mo_time_stamp
      from machine_status m
     ) m join
     calendar c
     on c.date >= date(mo_time_stamp) and c.date <= date(next_mo_time_stamp)
where c.date between ? and ?
```